# How to move up all columns in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this...

```
C_array D_array E_array
20.000    NA        NA
0.000     NA        NA
0.000     NA        NA
  NA      17.000    NA
  NA      17.000    NA
  NA      21.000    NA
  NA      49.000    NA
  NA      52.000    NA
  NA      NA      31.000
  NA      NA      31.000
  NA      NA      32.000
  NA      NA      32.000
  NA      NA      34.000
  NA      NA      34.000
  NA      NA      34.000
  NA      NA      34.000
  NA      NA      34.000
```

How can I remove the leading NA values? I want it to look like this...

```
C_array D_array E_array
20.000   17.000  31.000
0.000    17.000  31.000
0.000    21.000  32.000
  NA     49.000  32.000
  NA     52.000  34.000
  NA      NA     34.000
  NA      NA     34.000
  NA      NA     34.000
  NA      NA     34.000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could rearrange the `NA`s in each column so that the non-NA elements will be ordered before the NA and then subset the rows by removing rows having all `NA` values

```
df2 <- df1
df2[] <- lapply(df2, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))])
df2[rowSums(is.na(df2)) < ncol(df2),]
```

-output

```
 C_array D_array E_array
1      20      17      31
2       0      17      31
3       0      21      32
4      NA      49      32
5      NA      52      34
6      NA      NA      34
7      NA      NA      34
8      NA      NA      34
9      NA      NA      34
```

---

or do this in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ .[order(is.na(.))])) %>% 
    filter(!if_all(everything(), is.na))
  C_array D_array E_array
1      20      17      31
2       0      17      31
3       0      21      32
4      NA      49      32
5      NA      52      34
6      NA      NA      34
7      NA      NA      34
8      NA      NA      34
9      NA      NA      34
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(C_array = c(20, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), D_array = c(NA, NA, NA, 17, 
17, 21, 49, 52, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), E_array = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 31, 31, 32, 32, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

Comment: The lapply function you suggested worked perfectly! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option, but I'm a bit worried about the format, if being on the same row doesn't mean anything you might want to keep your result as a list and not a table.

```
res_list <- lapply(df, \(x) x[!is.na(x)]) # you might stop here
as.data.frame(lapply(res_list, `length<-`, max(lengths(res))))
#>   C_array D_array E_array
#> 1      20      17      31
#> 2       0      17      31
#> 3       0      21      32
#> 4      NA      49      32
#> 5      NA      52      34
#> 6      NA      NA      34
#> 7      NA      NA      34
#> 8      NA      NA      34
#> 9      NA      NA      34
```

Answer (score 0):

Are these real NA values or text strings stating like "NA"
If it is the first scenario:

```
df <- df[!is.na(df$E_array),]
```

otherwise

```
df <- df[df$E_array != "NA" ,]
```

Comment: This doesn't return the expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can use na.omit(YOURDATA) TO REMOVE na VALUES.

Comment: This won't work here

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```r
df <- structure(list(C_array = c(20L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                     D_array = c(NA, NA, NA, 17L, 17L, 21L, 49L, 52L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                     E_array = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))

l <- sapply(df, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
res <- sapply(l, function(x){length(x) <- max(lengths(l)); x})
res
#>       C_array D_array E_array
#>  [1,]      20      17      31
#>  [2,]       0      17      31
#>  [3,]       0      21      32
#>  [4,]      NA      49      32
#>  [5,]      NA      52      34
#>  [6,]      NA      NA      34
#>  [7,]      NA      NA      34
#>  [8,]      NA      NA      34
#>  [9,]      NA      NA      34
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of my solution.

Answer (score 0):

`stack`, `na.omit`, and `unstack` over columns and adapting `length`s as in [Moody's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69856555/6574038).

```
r <- stack(dat) |> na.omit() |> unstack() |>
  {\(x) lapply(x, `length<-`, max(lengths(x)))}() |>
  as.data.frame()
r
#   C_array D_array E_array
# 1      20      17      31
# 2       0      17      31
# 3       0      21      32
# 4      NA      49      32
# 5      NA      52      34
# 6      NA      NA      34
# 7      NA      NA      34
# 8      NA      NA      34
# 9      NA      NA      34
```

This keeps the result free of the `"na.action"` attribute.

```
str(r)
# 'data.frame': 9 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ C_array: num  20 0 0 NA NA NA NA NA NA
# $ D_array: num  17 17 21 49 52 NA NA NA NA
# $ E_array: num  31 31 32 32 34 34 34 34 34
```

*Note:*

```
R.version.string
# [1] "R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)"
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(C_array = c(20, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), D_array = c(NA, NA, NA, 17, 
17, 21, 49, 52, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), E_array = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 31, 31, 32, 32, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```